# How to do a popup text with information on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, mouseover

I have one database on my website with the data. I want to take this data and use it to display the information in popup.

For example: http://gameinfo.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/items/
Each icon show a popup with data.

There is a plugin or something?

Thanks.

Comment: a simple google search would have revealed everything you need to know, something like 'wordpress popup plugin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below plugin links, hope it will help you.

[1] http://wordpress.org/plugins/anything-popup/

[2] http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popup/

[3] http://www.designrazzi.com/2013/wordpress-popup-plugins/

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe Tippy Wordpress Plugin works. Do you know if it is possible I take informations from my database?

Comment: what r u talking about..? means what r u trying to ask me.?